# How do I set Xmodmap on login?

Tags: xmodmap, shortcut-keys

As my keyboard layout doesn't suit me, I run `xmodmap` on login. The script is named `.profile` and it runs OK, but it breaks the Unity interface.

I want to know where to put the `xmodmap` line so that it executes on my login and doesn't break anything.

I have already tried putting it in the `.bash_login` and `.bash_profile` files, without success (`xmodmap` doesn't set my keyboard).

What are my options?

Comment: How does it break the unity interface?

Comment: I would like to add that if your xmodmap execution time is too long, you should remove all entries that you did not modify by hand.
Keeping only the changes in your input file will make xmodmap run much faster.

Answer (score 45):

The correct place to put `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` (so that your changes are read at startup) is in `~/.xinitrc` (see explanation below), although you could alternately place the `xmodmap` command as a startup item (`/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/user/.Xmodmap`). I can say that for 12.04 (and presumably 12.10) that these two alternatives definitely do work, as either way they are read **after** you log in with `lightdm`. (I changed *Return* to *Right Shift*, and the change only took effect after entering my password and logging in).

**Please note:** if you are on Xfce, it is noted on the [official Xfce FAQ](https://wiki.xfce.org/faq) that you may have to create a startup item instead of using `~/.xinitrc`, and that you might have to delay the execution so the `xmodmap` changes are not overwritten by `setxkbmap`. You can use a delay to achieve this in your startup entry:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 20; /usr/bin/xmodmap /home/$USER/.Xmodmap"
```

(For the startup entry it is necessary to specify absolute paths)

Each time `setxkbmap` is run to change keyboard layout, you will have to run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` again in the terminal.

**Creating `~/.xinitrc`**

Create a file in your home folder called `.xinitrc` with

```
touch .xinitrc
```

and place in it:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Your `Xmodmap` file should **not** have entries in the `xmodmap -e " "` style as that is used in the terminal for temporarily setting the values. It must have entries in this format:

```
keycode 65 = Tab
keycode 23 = Space
```

It is often confusing which of the various `X` files (such as `.xprofile`, `.xinitrc`, etc) are read at startup, but `.xinitrc` does seem to be still read under 12.04, whereas `.Xmodmap` or `.xinputrc` are not read by themselves.

Comment: Note that if you make your changes with `xmodmap -e '...`, you can retrieve the right format for `xmodmap .Xmodmap` with `xmodmap -pke`, which prints out the current mapping - though you'll want to filter this down to just the lines that apply to the change you made.

Comment: This did not worked for me. I've created .Xmodmap and .xinitrc  | Then I placed  xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap into .xinitrc
And then inside .Xmodmad I have  keycode 166 = Prior
keycode 167 = Next

Comment: it's .xinitrc doesn't seem to be getting launched automatically anymore in Ubuntu 17.10. You'll have to autolaunch it with this command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && /home/USERNAME/.xinitrc"

Comment: On my Gentoo system, `${HOME}/.Xmodmap` is read by `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`, no need for `${HOME}/.xinitrc`. This should then work in _any_ X11-based graphical environment.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 16.04

Answer (score 18):

I'm using ElementaryOS (with its GNOME based window manager) and found a solution through using `xdg` autostart scripts. Many window managers are using xdg so I assume this approach also will work in other environments. At least it should work with GNOME.

xdg run scripts in `~/.config/autostart` upon login in a X session. To load xmodmap config upon login, add the following script to `~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name[en_US]=Xmodmap
Comment[en_US]=xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
Exec=/usr/bin/xmodmap .Xmodmap
Icon=application-default-icon
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Type=Application
```

Then logout and login again, and your Xmodmap configuration should've been loaded.

If it's not working, try to run xmodmap in terminal to see if it's xmodmap that complains:

```
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

If you don't get any error, run the following command to debug:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -B 5 -A 5 xmodmap
```

Comment: On Linux Mint 17 (based on: Ubuntu 14.04.5) the auto-start approach worked perfectly for me after using a `~/.xinitrc` file failed. As hxpax pointed out, Mint users (probably most/all Debian derived Linuxes) can use a GUI dialog to add auto-start entries by way of `Main Menu --> Preferences --> Startup Applications`.

Comment: Worked ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Worked on mint 21.1

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the unity interface in front of me just now, but try clicking the Applications button on the launcher, then type *startup*.

There should be an app called *Startup Applications* (or some such). Click it and add your xmodmap command (eg `xmodmap /home/thiago/.Xmodmap`).

It is important to **use** **absolute path**, **not** `~/Xmodmap`.
If it still doesn't work, you can try adding a bit of delay as suggested [by hxpax](https://askubuntu.com/a/838629/591187).

Comment: I tried that a while ago but it didn't work out for me. I'm on windows right now but I'll try again later and I report here if it works. thx

Comment: @Thiago Moraes Does this basic command work (if not, post the error)? `xmodmap .Xmodmap`

Comment: +1 this does work. To be more explicit I used the full path for .Xmodmap

Comment: this does not work. I am using 16.04

Comment: @miguelmorales85 does the basic command work in your terminal? did you try using an absolute path?

Comment: @djeikyb both xmodmap .Xmodmap and  /usr/bin/xmodmap .Xmodmap works like a charm when executed from cli. I have tried in ubuntu 16.06 inserting them into start up application , with and without quotes in the command field. I also tried inseting them into the file /etc/init.d/rc.local. I dont know what else to do.

Comment: @miguelmorales85 did you try using an absolute path to reference the settings file?

Comment: @djeikyb thank you, I was using ~/ for the path to the config file. I used /home/$USER and it worked. thank again

Answer (score 4):

On Mint 17/18, I can achieve that bu put my scripts into the Startup Application, with 1 second delay.

As Mint 18 is derived from Ubuntu 1604, I think you can do the same, or install Startup Application managing panel first if it is not there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 Works well. I needed no delay on Linux Mint 17.

Comment: @mattst Yeah, delay is optional.

Comment: I needed a delay of 5 seconds for this to work. I used the following startup shell script therefore: https://gist.github.com/ghagerer/58212241e37229f9d6fe3a133b34be97

Comment: I'd just like to add that it is important to use **full path** to your script, and not just`~/.Xmodemap`.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't having much joy with any of the suggestions above (the .bashrc option wasn't really viable as it runs xmodmap on every new terminal)

I touched a script called `xmodstartup.sh` in my home folder

```
  #!/bin/bash           
  sleep 1;               
  echo "running xmodmap" 
  xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

with it saved, I then did `sudo chmod +x xmodstartup.sh`

then I simply added the executable file to gnome's "startup application preferences" window.  bish bosh, English layout y Español on `altgr` :)

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. It's essentially the same as @GOST suggested but it runs a script which runs the command instead of directly running command. I don't know why but only this actually works on my system, even without the sleep timer.

Answer (score 2):

For gnome3:

xinitrc starts with `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` and contains only one command: `. /etc/X11/Xsession`
This global Xsession file sets paths that are being executed:

```
    USERXSESSION=$HOME/.xsession
    USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
```

I put `echo $(date) >> ~/sesscheck` in `$USERXSESSIONRC` to check if this file is being executed on gnome login. It works. However, if you put `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` instead of test file record, keys mapping stays default. It means that default xmodmap overrides settings when xinitrc already started.

As said above by @kontrollanten, the most reliable way is to create a `.desktop`  file and put it into `~/.config/autostart` directory.
Desktop entry example, modifying keymap after Gnome user login:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Correct keys layout
Exec=/usr/bin/xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Application;
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

In my case, I lost numpad functionality at all and needed to map numpad keycodes to exact digits. So, `~/.Xmodmap` is:

```
keycode  87 = 1 1 1 1 1 1
keycode  83 = 4 4 4 4 4 4
keycode  79 = 7 7 7 7 7 7
keycode  80 = 8 8 8 8 8 8
keycode  84 = 5 5 5 5 5 5
keycode  88 = 2 2 2 2 2 2
keycode  81 = 9 9 9 9 9 9
keycode  89 = 3 3 3 3 3 3
keycode  85 = 6 6 6 6 6 6
keycode  90 = 0 0 0 0 0 0
keycode  86 = plus plus plus plus plus plus
keycode  82 = minus minus minus minus minus minus
keycode  91 = period period period period period period
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that even .config/autostart is a bit finicky. Jay had a good solution but I've realized you could put the commands in xmodmap.desktop while just making sure to sleep the 1 second without having to make the extra bash script.

````
Name[en_US]=Xmodmap
Comment[en_US]=xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 1; /usr/bin/xmodmap .xmodmap"
Icon=application-default-icon
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Type=Application```
````

Answer (score -1):

Putting xmodmap changes in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` doesn't break anything.

Only downside is that one has to open a terminal after each boot to get it activated.

Comment: I'm already doing that, but the problem is that at every terminal I open, this command gets executed. It's only a moment but it's a little annoying and I would prefer a real solution. thx anyway