# How to run a particular command at startup?

Tags: scripts, autostart

I don't understand scripts or how to make them or how to run them. All I want to do is run the command `xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Delete"` when my computer starts. When I run this command in terminal, it remaps the PgDn key to be a second Delete key. But then I have to run it again every time I start the computer. How can I do this? I've tried adding it as a line in the `rc.local` file but it doesn't work.

Comment: Specifically for `xmodmap` commands there is another way of doing it: see [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login/211461#211461), but placing it in startup applications is fine as well, as has been suggested.

Answer (score 9):

You can make it run at boot by adding it in startup applications.  Open startup applications from the dash.  Click 'Add' and put `xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Delete"` in the 'Command' field.  Give it a name and comment if you want.  Click 'Add' and login again.

[image]

Comment: for opening startup manager from **Terminal** , you can use this command :‌ `gnome-session-properties`

Answer (score 5):

Seth's solution is a high-level solution that works fine as long as you don't change the desktop environment to something more exotic. To be on the secure side you might want to choose a method that acts at a lower level:

Open up a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and execute the following command:

```
echo "xmodmap -e \"keycode 112 = Delete"\" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

This appends `xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Delete"` to your `.bashrc` file and thus executes it on each login.

**Edit**: As Mik pointed out this might not be the best way of setting `xmodmap` up. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login/211461#211461) for a better method.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is not read at startup when you login with `lightdm`, but `~/.profile` is; so you could put it in there, or better still do what I suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login/211461#211461).

Comment: @Mik I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer +1.