# Trying to remap Caps Lock in Xubuntu, but Keyboard Layouts Plugin resets everything

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout, remapping

I am using Keyboard Layouts Plugin to switch between two layouts.

I want to remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to underscore `_`.

First I empty <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, or otherwise <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> will do both – toggle caps and produce underscore character and then map caps lock to underscore

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = "
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = underscore"
```

Problem?
This resets every time I log out or change something in Keyboard Layouts Plugin preferences.
I want this to be permanent.

Comment: See if this question helps: [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do/254425#254425)

Comment: @Aditya - I want to know how to remap a key permanently so that xfce doesn't reset it. That link does not address this issue.

Comment: Try the other suggestions given - `xbindkeys`, `xev`, etc along with `xmodmap`. I am sure they are written in a way that would bind the keys permanently. That question is pretty comprehensive. If you still face the issue, please update the question.

Comment: @Aditya - `setxkbmap -option caps:underscore` <-- why doesn't this do anything?

Comment: I won't be able to help you on this. I have no idea about the stuff. Neither can I find that code (`setxkbmap -option`) in any of the answers to that question. I would suggest you to edit your question to include what problems you are facing.

Comment: @Aditya - I think I said clearly that _Keyboard Layouts Plugin resets everything_

Comment: My answer [for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login/211461#211461) might be helpful, especially regarding the situation in Xfce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

Assuming you run a US layout, use this config:

```
[ids]

*

[main]

capslock = S-minus
```

This maps `CapsLock` to `Shift-Minus`, thus producing `_`.