# How to map <modifier> + hjkl to arrow key functionality?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I've been getting so used to vim's hjkl for moving around recently, and find myself wanting to use them right after alt tabbing out of vim.

What would be the best way to map fn + h/j/k/l to left/down/up/right?

edit: any `<modifier>` + h/j/k/l would be satisfactory as long as it doesn't conflict with other keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: is the _fn_ part really important?

Comment: I figured it would be a good choice to avoid shortcut collisions. But no, I'd settle with something else.

Comment: If you have a layout with AltGr enabled you can remap AltGr-hjkl  [using xmodmap](http://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395) (but excpect to have to call xmodmap often) or by [defining a new keyboard variant](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these, no guarantee if it will break anything, but I hope it won't:

1. if you look at the mapping by `xmodmap -pke`, you see it has four columns of characters mapped to each key, for different modifications. The order for these modifications is like

   `keycode  <x> = <1> <2> <3> <4>`

   `<1>                      <key>`

   `<2>                <shift-key>`

   `<3>        <"Mode_switch"-key>`

   `<4>  <shift-"Mode_switch"-key>`
2. "Mode_switch", not completely sure, but I guess maps to nothing by default. Actually, you can see the code for the key with `xmodmap` and looking for it somewhere at the bottom of the results and finding out what key that code belongs to. What I did was I reassinged it to another key, for example `Super_L`, which is the lefp super key, with these:

   ```
   xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Mode_switch"
   ```

   or you can put your own choise in place of `Super_L`
3. Now, go ahead and edit the column for the four keys you wanted to reassign. Let's find them in your `xmodmap` file:

   ```
   xmodmap -pke | grep h
   ```

   among the output should be line which says

   ```
   keycode 43 = h H h H
   ```

   edit it so that it's like

   ```
   keycode 43 = h H Left H
   ```

   to do that, use the command

   ```
   xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H Left H"
   ```

   and then try if it worked.
4. Do that for the rest of the keys you want to map.

I think this is not likely to break anything serious, as long as you can go back and reedit the `keycode`s to their originals. The only scary part was where I mapped "Mode_switch" to Super_L. (**Edit**: this actually disabled my super key, which I was able to get back to work by reversing the assignment, that's `xmodmap -e "keysym Mode_switch = Super_L"`. Map a key you know would not fail you to Mode_switch)

Comment: I had to use this to make AltGr+h work asl left arrow: `xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H h H Left Hstroke hstroke"`

Answer (score 3):

While I sympathize with you (I have a Happy Hacking keyboard, and would love to have the same layout on my laptop, with Fn + ;'[/ for left right up down respectively), the Function key `Fn` is almost always implemented entirely in the hardware, and there is no way to bind it as a modifier key in software.

Answer (score 1):

If **any** modifier will do, then the following work for `AltGr` using `xmodmap`.

First, find the keycodes for `h,j,k` and `l`. This may be done running `xev` in terminal, then pressing the respective keys. For me, the keycode for `h` is `43`. To map this plus `AltGr` to `left`, use the command

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H NoSymbol NoSymbol Left"
```

Repeat for the remaining keys, and you'll be done :)
To set on start up, see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login).

Answer (score 1):

Since some time `xmodmap` is depricated! to get a system wide setting you have to use `xkb`. So edit the language file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` to add your changes there.

see https://askubuntu.com/a/898462/34298

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example using `Alt_l` as the modifier, tested w/ Ubuntu 21.04

```sh
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Mode_switch" # set Alt_l as the "Mode_switch"
xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H Left H" # h
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J Down J" # j
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K Up K" # k
xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L Right L" # l
```

note: you can use the `xev` command to find the keycode for any key you may want to use as the modifier

Comment: This solution works good in Xubuntu 22.04, thanks.