# How to map [Alt] + [hjkl] keys to arrow keys?

Tags: xmodmap

I know how to map [AltGr] + [h|j|k|l] keys to arrow keys, like:

```
[AltGr]+[h] ... [Left]  
[AltGr]+[j] ... [Down]  
[AltGr]+[k] ... [Up]  
[AltGr]+[l] ... [Right]  

[AltGr]+[ö] ... [Home]  
[AltGr]+[ä] ... [End]
```

This is possible in two steps:

**Step 1)** Find the keycodes:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep "h H h H"  
keycode  43 = h H h H hstroke Hstroke hstroke  
$ xmodmap -pke | grep "j J j J"  
keycode  44 = j J j J dead_belowdot dead_abovedot dead_belowdot  
$ xmodmap -pke | grep "k K k K"  
keycode  45 = k K k K kra ampersand kra  
$ xmodmap -pke | grep "l L l L"  
keycode  46 = l L l L lstroke Lstroke lstroke  
$
$ xmodmap -pke | grep "odiaeresis" ## search for the diaresis 'ö'
keycode  47 = odiaeresis Odiaeresis odiaeresis Odiaeresis dead_doubleacute dead_belowdot dead_doubleacute
$ xmodmap -pke | grep "adiaeresis" ## search for the diaresis 'ä'
keycode  48 = adiaeresis Adiaeresis adiaeresis Adiaeresis dead_circumflex dead_caron dead_circumflex
$ ## as we can see the keycodes are: h=43, j=44, k=45, l=46, ö=47, ä=48
```

According to
[ubuntuusers.de/Xmodmap/](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Xmodmap/)
the syntax to remap the keys is the following:

`$ xmodmap -e "keycode <keycode> = <key1> <key2> <key3> <key4> <key5> <key6>"`

```
<key1> ...             <Key>
<key2> ...       <Shift-Key>
<key3> ...         <Alt-Key>
<key4> ...   <Shift-Alt-Key>
<key5> ...       <AltGr-Key> (at least by Unity)
<key6> ... <Shift-AltGr-Key> (at least by Unity)
```

**Step 2)** Map the keys to your desire:

```
$ ##                       1 2 3        4        5      6
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H NoSymbol NoSymbol Left   NoSymbol"  
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J NoSymbol NoSymbol Down   NoSymbol"  
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K NoSymbol NoSymbol Up     NoSymbol"  
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L NoSymbol NoSymbol Right  NoSymbol"  
$ ##                       1          2          3        4        5
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 47 = odiaeresis Odiaeresis NoSymbol NoSymbol Home"
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 48 = adiaeresis Adiaeresis NoSymbol NoSymbol End"
```

**Problem:** However when i try to map it to [Alt] instead of [AltGr] nothing happens, i.e. neither my cursor moves according to my desired direction, nor any characters get print.

```
$ ##                       1 2 3     4        5        6
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H Left  NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol"  
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J Down  NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol"  
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K Up    NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol"  
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L Right NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol"
```

The main reason for remapping those keys is to avoid moving my right hand always to the arrow keys while working in the ATOM text editor. So i want to be able to navigate in atom like in vim or in ranger with hjkl.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using xubuntu 16.0.4 and encountered similar issue before. My solution was to run below first before any `xmodmap` commands:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant altgr-intl -option nodeadkeys
```

You may need to adjust the parameters to fit your keyboard layout.

Comment: `$ setxkbmap -layout de -variant altgr-intl -option nodeadkeys` gives me "Error loading new keyboard description" back.

Comment: What's the output of the command `setxkbmap -query` ?

Comment: `~$ setxkbmap -query`  
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     de
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/466315/357970), the third key is actually a `Mode_switch` key which is not set by default

Here's the full solution i'm using on Pop!_OS 21.04

```sh
#########################
## add `alt` + `h/j/k/l` => left/up/down/right - per vim bindings
## - https://shellhell.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/hello-world/
## - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025765/how-to-map-alt-hjkl-keys-to-arrow-keys
## - https://askubuntu.com/questions/465924/how-to-map-modifier-hjkl-to-arrow-key-functionality
#########################
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Mode_switch" # set Alt_l as the "Mode_switch"
xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H Left H" # h
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J Down J" # j
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K Up K" # k
xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L Right L" # l
```

and [if you stick these in your `~/.profile`](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980), they'll be set on boot