# Bind alt + wasd to arrow keys

Tags: xmodmap

I tried what the OP did in [How to map [Alt] + [hjkl] keys to arrow keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025765/how-to-map-alt-hjkl-keys-to-arrow-keys) and faced the same issue. The only answer did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any solutions? I am on Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work by specifying left alt as my mode switch.

```
keycode 64 = NoSymbol NoSymbol
keycode 64 = Mode_switch
keycode 25 = w W Up NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
```