# Xmodmap problem blocks connection via x2go

Tags: 16.04, xmodmap, nx, x2go, x2goclient

I have a remote server with x2go, in the remote .profile I call xmodmap. The call of xmodmap throws a warning: xmodmap: unable to open display ''
This was until the upgrade to ubuntu 16.04.1 no problem I could just connect via a x2go client. But since 16.04.1 this message is passed to the client and the connection process is stopped. 
I have read some where that x2go uses now the option: `set -e` so I tried to do a `set +e`before the call of xmodmap in .profile but unfortunately this did not solve the problem.
Does any one else has an idea, how I either can solve the initial problem or fix it in x2go.

Thanks a lot for any hint.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a step back and trying to figure out how to move your `xmodmap` command out of `.profile` (which IMHO isn't the right place for any X session related stuff): see for example this answer to [How do I set Xmodmap on login?](http://askubuntu.com/a/211461/178692)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much this brought me on the right track. I have moved away from xmodmap und use now keboardmaping.

```
cp keypad kpdl /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```